# Cut and paste the last 8 characters of a string VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, worksheet-function

Hi I want to be able to use VBA to take the last 8 characters of a string and cut and paste them in a table on another sheet and then go back to the string and take the next 8 characters and cut & paste them in another column in my table and so on until there is nothing left in the string and as it is for a very long spreadsheet so I want to be able to loop it through out each row. Any ideas on how?

Comment: Specify the columns and does the table have some kind of separator? You can use `Len` to get the length of the string and if the length is `>8` you can use `Right` and get the last 8 characters and then delete the last 8, however, you could just get the length and loop to get 8 by 8 characters and paste to each column.

Answer (score 1):

I think ojf is along the right lines that this doesnt need to be done using vba. on a new sheet, generate values 1,2,3,4 etc. in the top row, then in A2 use formula:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT([your long string cell],8*A1),8)
```

and drag it along to the right as many times as you need. make sure to lock the reference to your string using f4. Also beware, this will create trailing duplicates.